# Why I need to place my click listeners in onCreate and not in my Adapter

Tags: android

I am new to android and I came across to something , why I have to put my clicklisteners inside on Create method and not in my adapter?

Comment: You can put your click listener inside your adaoter

Comment: you can put your click listener any where but make sure that got create on which you are setting click listener.

Answer (score 0):

your adapter can also have onclick listeners if you are using a custom adapter. 
and you should always put your onclicklisteners in oncreate because your buttons should listen to the clicks after the activity is created

or you can try using implements View.OnClickListener after extends activity then implement the methods to have a much more cleaner code

please refer to this site

https://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/how-to-implements-onclicklistener-for-a-view-item-in-android/

provides a tutorial on how to use the cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

`Listener` can be set or clear as soon as the operation is done on a object with a valid state (e.g a not null referenced button)

so you are not technically forced to set the onClicklistener in the `onCreate` method, **normally** it is done in that method because is in there where you initialize/prepare the widgets of the activity so after that preparation step your button is "ready to go"